# Reset keyboard remap permanently

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard, keyboard-layout, pop-os

I had the brilliant idea to switch the FN key and CTRL key on my lenovo laptop keyboard which I now after 3-4 months realize was the biggest mistake I've ever made in any linux distro. This didn't really work as expected and I found a way to set this back to normal by running:

```
setxkbmap -option
```

Only whenever I restart I have to run this command again.

I've tried adding this as a startup command, adding it to .profile file and some other stuff but for some reason seems to only work whenever i enter it by hand.

Is there any way to permanently set this keyboard layout?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Regards,
Jelle

Comment: So how did you swap `FN` and `CTRL` initially?

Comment: It was a while ago but i believe to swap those i had to swap superuser and fn in bios then I used setxkbmap to swap superuser and ctrl

Comment: @GamingTurtle Do you have a Lenovo Thinkpad ?  In that case you can change this mapping in BIOS/UEFI . No need to do remapping

Comment: So undo that in the BIOS first - the `FN` key is usually a major PITA to handle from the OS side.